# How do I implement paging on a route with other parameters?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, paging

I know how to implement paging on a route when there's a single route such as /Dinners/Page/1. My issue is that I have a list of articles. These articles are sat in categories and subcategories.

If no category/subcategory is specified I want to return all articles.
If only category is supplied I supply all articles in that category
If category and subcategory are supplied I want only the articles in the subcategory.

I had this working no problem. Then I wanted to add paging. I wanted a route that could do the following:
domain.com/6 - goes to page 6 of all articles
domain.com/category/2 - goes to page 2 of category articles
domain.com/category/subcategory/3 - goes to page 3 of subcategory articles

I can't get this working because the first example is looking for category 6, the second is looking for category 2. I've tried adding a constraint in the hope the numeric value would be attributed to page. No joy.

Also, I want to do this server side.

Any ideas? Here's the route in my RouteConfig:

```
   routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Category",
                url: "{category}/{subcategory}/{page}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Articles", action = "Index", category= UrlParameter.Optional, subcategory = UrlParameter.Optional, page = UrlParameter.Optional }
                //, constraints: new { page = @"\d+" }
            );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I played around with the route and added three routes to replace the original.

The first one captures the view all with the paging. If no paging is provided I just display the first page. The second route is the main category with paging.

The third route covers off if there is a subcategory. This is working like a charm now. :)

Here are my routes in case you want to know exactly what I did:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Paged",
            url: "{page}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Articles", action = "Index", page = UrlParameter.Optional }, 
            constraints: new { page = @"\d+" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "PagedCategory",
            url: "{category}/{page}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Articles", action = "Index", category = UrlParameter.Optional, page = UrlParameter.Optional }
            //, constraints: new { page = @"\d+" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "PagedSubCategory",
            url: "{category}/{subcategory}/{page}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Articles", action = "Index", category = UrlParameter.Optional, subcategory = UrlParameter.Optional, page = UrlParameter.Optional }
            //, constraints: new { page = @"\d+" }
        );
```

Comment: Yes, nice job!! Sometimes its easy to work around if you have full code in hand. Well, this is indeed new knowledge feed for me Thanks :)

Comment: Note in the 2nd and 3rd routes, you should remove `category = UrlParameter.Optional` and `subcategory = UrlParameter.Optional` (only the last parameter can be optional)

Answer (score -1):

Pass page number as querystring parameter, like: `category/subcategory?page=1`.

Or change you route like this,

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Category",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{category}/{subcategory}/{page}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Articles", action = "Index", category= UrlParameter.Optional, subcategory = UrlParameter.Optional, page = UrlParameter.Optional }
                //, constraints: new { page = @"\d+" }
            );
```

Hope this works, thank you.

Comment: That breaks everything completely. domain.com/category etc don't even work now even with paging.

Comment: I want to avoid appending to the query string really, I'd like a nice clean url structure.